# onTouchListener doing action twice

Tags: android, spinner, listeners, ontouch

I am trying to make some field with text (no button) what I click on to open datepicker dialog.
I am totally begginer and I am trying it on easy example.

```
 firstbirth.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ahooj", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

firstbirth is spinner, I tried it with Edittext and the result was same.
Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Use an OnClickListener instead.

```
setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)
```

OnTouchListeners will trigger on multiple touch events (like touch down, touch up etc.) whereas the OnClickListener will only get fired once (onClick :) )

If you, for some reason, want to use an OnTochListener you can make sure that its only called once.

Try:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP {   // another option would be ACTION_DOWN for example
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ahooj", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP  did the trick thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it sounds logical but when I use OnClick event application felt down while initializing.

```
 firstbirth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               DialogFragment dd1 = new DatePickerFragment();
               dd1.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select a date");
            }
 });
```

Problem is not with DialogFragment becasue it works when I use onTouch event.
Thanks :)

Comment: not sure what you mean with felt down. If you want to use onTouch see the edit in my answer.

Comment: I mean "Unfortnuately, application .. stop working".

Comment: Your solution is really great, it works nice! Thanks :)